# reactjs Question for parsing string to HTML

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-parsing

I am getting jSON from api after that I am converting that to string of HTML in the form of ul li and then I am passing it as props to parent component but it is rendering as HTML in render method

I try to render with dangerouslySetInnerHTML and ReactHtmlParser but both parse inside div and I don't parse inside div it should be parse directly

**Child Component**

```
render(): React.ReactElement<ISidebarContentProps & RouteComponentProps> {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <div id='sidebar-menu'>
                    <ul className='metismenu list-unstyled' id='side-menu'>
                      {this.props.listItem}
                    </ul>
                </div>
            <React.Fragment>
         )
}
```

**Parent Component**

```
render(): React.ReactElement<ISidebarProps> {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <div className='vertical-menu'>
                    <div data-simplebar className='h-100'>
                        {this.props.type !== 'condensed' ? (
                            <SimpleBar style={{ maxHeight: '100%' }}>
                                <SidebarContent type={this.props.type} listItem={this.listItem} />
                            </SimpleBar>
                        ) : (
                            <SidebarContent type={this.props.type} listItem={this.listItem} />
                        )}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
```

Kindly let me know best way to parse and do I working correct way. Please considered me as newbie to reactjs

Comment: Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Hello any one!!